# Ambiguity with あまり

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

I was thinking of giving an answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57636/is-%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-correct-for-not-often), but then I remembered that my Japanese is rubbish.

I was going to give an example:

> ケーキはあまり食べない

Then I started having doubts about whether this would mean "I don't often eat cake" or "I don't eat much cake", i.e. "When I eat cake, I only eat a small slice".

Without context, can the sentence have both of these interpretations?

Comment: Please try to avoid writing answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. We judge it by context as you knew. If you want to make sure that you mean "I only eat a small slice", you can say "ケーキは少ししか食べない".

I interpret ケーキはあまり食べない as "I don't often eat cake", because I feel it says "one's preference" or "custom".

For example, あまり旅行しない would mean "I don't often go on a trip.", 今日はあまり酒を飲まなかった would mean "I didn't drink much today" rather than "I didn't often drink today".

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding `because I feel it says "one's favor"`.  Could you explain what you mean by this part?

Comment: I interpret it as "I don't habitually eat cake because I don't like it very", not "transient quantity", because present tense can mean "habit".

Comment: `one's favor` 「好み」ってことですかね？ one's preference とか。。。

Comment: Yes, I chose a wrong word. Thank you for teaching.